# webkit-filter breaks overflow: hidden

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, overflow

It seems I've run across a weird rendering bug that was introduced in Google Chrome 27.

If you have a container with a `webkit-filter` and children element with `overflow: hidden` the overflowed content inside of that element won't be hidden as expected, as can be seen in [this test case](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/P3ysJ/).

Any ideas on how to work around this bug? I especially need drop-shadow/box-shadow (webkit and mozilla respectively) to work on table rows which is why I have that in the test case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wow, this one took forever. So you're right, Chrome 27 has a bug with the overflow property when a webkit filter is applied to a PARENT element.

so... if you apply a filter to the same element that you apply the overflow property to, it will work.

http://jsfiddle.net/P3ysJ/8/

```
.bar {
    position: relative;
    width: 11px;
    height: 8px;
    -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Didn't even think about trying a filter on the container. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yeah, it took me a minute to think of it also. I tried just about every other css property first... :-)

Comment: Everyone that's affected by this bug should star the issue here – https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=265429

Comment: This still appears to be a bug, at least on Mac. Doesn't seem to affect Windows.