# Backdrop filter not working with overflow: hidden on parent

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use backdrop-filter(blur in this case) on a div only to discover the overflow: hidden property prevents it from applying. The browser is Chrome 78.

Say I've got a div.filter inside a div.block that's wrapper inside a div.container.

div.container > div.block > div.filter

If I apply overflow: hidden to both .container and .block the effect of the filter suddenly disappears. Furthermore, other properties of the .block prevents the filter from being applied.

Seems like the overflow: hidden on .container triggers this erratic behavior. Do you guys have any idea what's going on here?

Demo here: https://codepen.io/marcel_pi/pen/VwYvmGv

Please check the code below:

```css
.container{
  overflow: hidden;  /* delete to resume normal behavior */
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.block{
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 4px solid black;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 50%, rgba(152,47,138,.5) 50%) antiquewhite;
  background-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  
  /* the properties below prevent the filter from being applied once the overflow: hidden is applied to .container */
  
  border-radius: 20px; /* delete to resume normal behavior */
  overflow: hidden; /* delete to resume normal behavior */
  position: relative; /* delete to resume normal behavior */
}

.filter{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 205px;
  width: 230px;
  height: 230px;
  background: #42add77d;
  backdrop-filter: blur(6px); /* the blur filter */
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
  <div class="block">
    <div class="filter"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 9):

If you apply a filter (`0px`) to the same element that you apply the overflow property to, it will work.

```css
.container{
  overflow: hidden;  /* delete to resume normal behavior */
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.block{
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 4px solid black;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 50%, rgba(152,47,138,.5) 50%) antiquewhite;
  background-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  
  /* the properties below prevent the filter from being applied once the overflow: hidden is applied to .container */
  
    -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
  border-radius: 20px; /* delete to resume normal behavior */
  overflow: hidden; /* delete to resume normal behavior */
  position: relative; /* delete to resume normal behavior */
}

.filter{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 205px;
  width: 230px;
  height: 230px;
  background: #42add77d;
  backdrop-filter: blur(4px);
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
  <div class="block">
    <div class="filter"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

You can test it [here](https://codepen.io/nimittshah/pen/BayopOq) as well..

Answer (score 3):

It's a stacking order issue. If you do a simple test of adding, `z-index` to your `block` element, you'll see the filter working as expected.

I did a little digging around about `overflow` and how it's properties affect stacking order, but couldn't find any conclusive documentation.

That said, just add `z-index: 1` to your `block`.

**Caveat**: This will not work on Firefox unless you set the layout.css.backdrop-filter.enabled preference to true in about:config.

### February 2024 Update

Firefox no longer requires the config change for this.

https://caniuse.com/#search=backdrop-filter

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  /* delete to resume normal behavior */
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.block {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 4px solid black;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 50%, rgba(152, 47, 138, .5) 50%) antiquewhite;
  background-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.filter {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 205px;
  width: 230px;
  height: 230px;
  background: #42add77d;
  backdrop-filter: blur(4px);
  border-radius: 20px;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="block">
    <div class="filter"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There were some bugs in Chrome with `filter` / `backdrop-filter`, `border-radius` and `overflow: hidden`:

- Asked in May 2013 (Chrome 27): [webkit-filter breaks overflow: hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16717665/webkit-filter-breaks-overflow-hidden)
- Asked in April 2016: [Backdrop Filter extends beyond Border Radius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36378512/backdrop-filter-extends-beyond-border-radius).

  Should be fixed already: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=142662.

For me, the only property that is not working is `.block`'s `overflow: hidden`, but you can just remove it, position `.filter` so that it doesn't overflow and apply its `border-radius` only to the corners that need it (in this example, `border-radius: 0 4px 0 16px`):

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  margin: 16px;
  padding: 16px;
  border: 4px solid black;
  border-radius: 12px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.block {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 4px solid black;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 50%, rgba(152,47,138,.5) 50%) antiquewhite;
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  
  /* This is the only one what won't work: */
  /* overflow: hidden; */
}


.filter {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background: #42ADD77D;
  backdrop-filter: blur(4px);
  
  /*
    Add border-radius only top right corner (which should match the parent's border-radius minus its
    border-width) and bottom left corner:
  */
  
  border-radius: 0 4px 0 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">
    <div class="filter"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm using Chrome `Version 78.0.3904.108 (Official Build) (64-bit)` on Windows 10.