# CSS backdrop-filter:blur in Safari and Chrome render problem

Tags: html, css

```css
body{
  background: #555;
}
#container{
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  position: relative;
}
#content{
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  margin:50px;
  position: absolute;
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

[This is on Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWhST.png) (This is what I want and should be)

[This is on Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZqqJ.png) (This is wrong.)

There is a problem here. If an object's parent and itself has the backdrop-filter property, this works fine in Safari browser but doesn't apply this CSS property to chrome child object. or not render. Is this a mistake? If it is error how can I solve it? Thanks for your help.

(!!!) EDIT : The mess that is created ruins everything. The solution is valid for simple objects, but not a valid method for complex objects.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Backdrop filter not working with overflow: hidden on parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59218666/backdrop-filter-not-working-with-overflow-hidden-on-parent)

Comment: Thank you, but this is not the answer to my question because I don't want it to be overflow hidden. There will be a shape like in the pictures and both objects will have a backdrop-filter. This is the correct one in the safari example but there is a problem with the chrome browser. Does not apply filter to object that is child.

Answer (score 6):

`backdrop-filter` has poor support in chrome, there is a work-around to do it with CSS pseudo elements `:after` or `:before` :

```css
body{
  background: #555;
}
#container{
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  position: relative;
}

#container:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
}

#content{
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  margin:50px;
  position: absolute;
}


#content:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue. Webkit prefix not work for me. If you have some animation so element is not visible on start backdrop filter not working in safari. Just set 1px height and it's start working.

You can check more details in this topic - [-webkit-backdrop-filter not working on Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69904893/webkit-backdrop-filter-not-working-on-safari)

Comment: This appears to be true, but it should not be true xD. People should be able to have dynamic elements with support for backdrop filters. I made my own private UI library as a React alternative which supports enter and exit animations for all components. The problem is..... All of my components are now technically "dynamic" and since they are not mounted at like 0ms, apparently Safari won't blur them...

Comment: Yea if you want work with dynamic pages which have lot of animations, I very recomend to check every effect on safari, because safari have lot of specifics on this...

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>


    <style>
        body{
            background: #555;
        }
        #container{
            height: 150px;
            width: 150px;
            background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
            position: relative;
        }
        #container::before {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
        }
        #content{
            height: 150px;
            width: 150px;
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
            margin:50px;
            position: absolute;
            backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="content"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and attention. It is necessary to use the content property together with before and after. This again leads to confusion. Some rendering errors can occur when you use a border or border-radius.