# -webkit-backdrop-filter not working on Safari

Tags: css, safari, webkit

Safari 14.1.2 not showing `-webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);`
I have tried multiple versions, inline, with jQuery, with `@supports` but nothing works.
Strangest thing is that it is shown as enabled in Safari 'Web Inspector' and works if I toggle it off and back one again. What could be the solution? Is there any workarounds?

Comment: Please could you add a workable snippet to your question so we can see the problem for ourselves See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: How does this page look like in your Safari? https://webkit.org/demos/backdrop-filter/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hithere,

I had the same Problem.
My Issue was my not 'visible' div in the Beginning. (Bottom-Top-Slideanimation)

```
 div{
            height: 0px,
            bottom: 0px,
            -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
            backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
    }
```

My solution was:

```
  div{
                height: 1px,
                bottom: -1px,
                -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
                backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
        }
```

Now it works.

I hope this is a Solution for you.

Greetings,
Simerl

Comment: Thanks, this answer help me lot of. I have slider with blur effect and it doesn't work. I hope that apple fix this.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a satisfying solution. I created my own private web UI tool as an alternative to React with full enter and exit animations on every component. It works really well, but based on this solution, it seems that if my components are not immediately mounted/visible, then backdrop blurring will not work in Safari. This definitely is a mistake on Safari's part.

Comment: IE vibes coming up...

Comment: In my case it's the background of a navigation panel that is not immediately visible. Since the panel is animated with gsap, I give the background blur dynamically before it opens. nonsensical, but it works.