# Issue with backdrop-filter: blur() in safari

Tags: html, css

In the same page I have two components with the property backdrop-filter: blur(17px).  In big screens (more than 2500px) using safari, the second component loses the property keeping it only in the first component.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FU9n0.jpg)

What is the problem? What should I do to use both blur?

I have tried adding webkit-backdrop-filter and the issue persists.

Comment: Please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69904893/webkit-backdrop-filter-not-working-on-safari

Answer (score 0):

In the description, you prefixed it with "webkit-" instead of "-webkit-". Perhaps this is the problem?
In Safari, this property must be used with the -webkit- prefix. On the "Can I use" site, this is exactly what is indicated for the latest version of Safari.

https://caniuse.com/?search=backdrop-filter%3A

Referring to the data of this site, everything should work

Comment: I added -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(17.5px) and still the same thing happens. 
The weird thing is that using the same component on the same page, the first one is fine but the second one breaks on huge screens.